# sequelize "findbyid" is not a function but apparently "findAll" is

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am getting a very strange problem with sequelize, When I try to call the function findAll it works fine (same for create and destroy), but when I try to call function "findById", it throws "findById is not a function" (same for "FindOne").

```
//works fine
var gammes = models.gamme.findAll().then(function(gammes) {
        res.render('admin/gammes/gestion_gamme',{
            layout: 'admin/layouts/structure' ,
            gammes : gammes,
            js: "gammes"
        });
    });

// throws models.gamme.findById is not a function
models.gamme.findById(req.params.id).then(function(gamme) {
        gamme.update({
            nom: req.body.nom
        }).then(function () {
            res.redirect("/gammes");
        })
    });
```

Gamme.js model

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    "use strict";
    var gamme = sequelize.define('gamme', {
        id_gamme: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        nom: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        classMethods: {},
        timestamps: false
    });
    return gamme;
};
```

Comment: Can you let us know the sequelize version you are using

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrade-from-2.0-to-3.0

Comment: thanks a lot ! I was consulting the documentation of sequelize 2, but the installed version was 1.7

Answer (score 165, accepted):

With Sequelize v5, findById() was replaced by findByPk(). Replace findById using findByPk and everything should work fine. You can find query doc [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html)

Comment: what leads you to believe that the OP is using v5?  do you see the comment about the installed version being v1.7?

Comment: Well I just upgraded from Sequelize 4.33.2 to 5.8.6 and this fixed my issue.

Comment: i try in sequelize version 6.13.0 , findByPk() will working fine

Answer (score 10):

the team of sequelize was deleting this function and replced it by a new function is

> findByPk

like this

```
// search for known ids
Project.findByPk(123).then(project => {
  // project will be an instance of Project and stores the content of the table entry
  // with id 123. if such an entry is not defined you will get null
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly pass value.

```
Question.findByPk(question_id).then(question => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                question: question
           });
}).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
});
```